# Min and max of a product.

Tags: optimization

Let $x_i\in X_i\subset \mathbb{R}$ so that each $X_i$ is a compact set with no isolated points for all $1\leq i\leq n$.

Let:

$a_i\in X_i$ so that $|x_i|\leq|a_i|$ for all $x_i\in X_i$.

$b_i = \max\lbrace x_i \in X_i\rbrace$.

$c_i = \min\lbrace x_i \in X_i\rbrace$.

$f:\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ so that:

$$f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^nx_i$$

Also let 
$$A = \prod_{i=1}^na_i$$

Then obviously:

If $A > 0\ $  (i.e. there's an even amount of negative $a_i$) then $A = \max f$

If $A < 0\ $ (i.e. there's an odd amount of negative $a_i$) then $A = \min f$.

How to find $\max f$ if $A <0$ and $\min f$ if $A > 0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum of $|f|$ is realized by taking $x_i = |a_i| = \max\{|b_i|,|c_i|\}$ and, as you noticed, is given by $A$.

Now it is clear that to get the maximum of $f$ you must choose $x_i \in \{b_i,c_i\}$ (an extremal point) because the function $f$ is multilinear and hence intermediate points give intermediate values. So you can actually assume that $X_i = \{c_i, b_i\}$

*First case.* Suppose that $s(b_i) = s(c_i)$ for all $i$, where $s(x)$ is the sign of $x$.
In this case the problem is easily solved... If the number of negative signs is even, the maximum is reached by taking $x_i = b_i$ if $|b_i|>|c_i|$ and $x_i=c_i$ otherwise. If you want the minimum take the point with minimum absolute value. If the number of negative signs is odd you get maximum and minimum exchanged.

*Second case.* if at least for one $i$ you have $s(b_i)=-s(c_i)$ you consider the point $x_i\in \{b_i,c_i\}$ which realize the maximum of $|f|$ (i.e. take the maximum between $|b_i|$ and $|c_i|$). If in this point $|f|=f$ you have found the maximum of $f$. Otherwise $|f|=-f$ but you have the possibility to change an odd number of $x_i$ so that the sign of $f$ changes. If you change the value of $x_i$ from, say, $b_i$ to $c_i$ the value of $f$ diminishes by a factor $|c_i|/|b_i|$ which is always $\le 1$. So the best choice is to change a single point and precisely choose $i$ so that $s(b_i)=-s(c_i)$ and $|c_i|/|b_i|$ is as close as possible to 1. A similar reasoning applies to the minimum.

**alternative construction (presumably more clear)**

As noted above you can suppose that $X_i = \{ b_i, c_i\}$. Moreover you can possibly change the sign of some $X_i$ so to obtain $c_i = |c_i| > |b_i|$ for all $i$. If you change the sign to an even number of $X_i$ then $\max f$ and $\min f$ are preserved, otherwise $\max f$ and $\min f$ are exchanged.

In this situation one obviously has $\max f = \max |f| = \prod c_i = A$. The point is to find $\min f$.

*First case.* If $b_i\ge 0$ for all $i$ then, obviously, $\min f = \prod b_i$.

*Second case.* If $b_i<0$ for some $i$, then take the index $i$ such that $b_i<0$ and $|b_i|/c_i$ (which is $\le 1$) is maximum. Then $\min f = \frac{b_i}{c_i}\prod c_i < 0$.
This is justified by the fact that in this case the minimum is negative so we must choose $x_i = b_i<0$ for an odd number of $i$s. Since any choice of $b_i$ instead of $c_i$ decreases the absolute value of the product by a factor $|b_i|/c_i$ (which is less than 1) it is convenient to make only one change of sign and to choose the index so as to maximize such a factor.